# How to search for all points in a given radius of a zipcode?

Tags: php, zipcode

I want to have a search form with two fields, one for zipcode and other for distance in miles(radius). So whenever I enter the zipcode and radius, then it should search all the zipcodes with in that radius of zipcode. e.g If I enter the zipcode 10001 and distance is 3miles then this form should search all the zipcodes around the 3 miles radius of 10001. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you.
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn../trunk/fusiontables/circle_example.html

Regards,
ArunRaj.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Arun Raj. Actually I want some script or tutorials link or some thing like that from which I can make my mind..

Comment: @user3376865 : Just debug the example with Firebug. That is a perfect webpage for beginner to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find (latitude, longitude) from zip code, then you can try as below:

```
"SELECT *,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) ) * cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) * cos( radians( `longitude` ) - radians({$lng}) ) + sin( radians({$lat}) ) * sin( radians( `latitude` ) ) ) ) AS distance
 FROM `open_stores` HAVING `distance` <= {$radius} ORDER BY distance ASC";
```